# Unable to get presentViewController to work

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller

I copied a working viewcontroller class from another project into a new project. I can't get the view to load in the new project. In the old project I used presentModalViewController. In the new I cannot get the view to load using either presentModalViewController or presentViewController

I am trying to load the present the view from my main view controller.

Here is what my main view controller interface looks like...

```
//  ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RequestDialogViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <RequestDialogViewControllerDelegate> {

}

- (void)requestDialogViewDidDismiss:(RequestDialogViewController *)controller withResponse:(NSString*)response;
```

I am using presentModalViewController like this...

```
RequestDialogViewController *requestIPViewController = [[RequestDialogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RequestDialogViewController"  bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:requestIPViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

and presentViewController like this...

```
RequestDialogViewController *requestIPViewController = [[RequestDialogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RequestDialogViewController"  bundle:nil];    
[self presentViewController:requestIPViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What am I missing in the new project? The init method fires, but viewDidLoad does not and nothing is displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If `ViewController` is the root view controller, it can't present a modal view controller from within its own `viewDidLoad`, because at that point it doesn't have information like the screen size.

If other view controllers have already displayed, this will work.  If the root view controller is a `UINavigationController`, you will see a view sliding in from the right while the modal view slides up from the bottom.

Anyway, for your `ViewController`, the soonest you could present it is after it has become visible.  Using a timer for this is unreliable; older and slower devices have dramatically longer load times.

For more reliability, implement `viewDidAppear:` for `ViewController`.  Do still use your timer system to add an additional delay; a fraction of a second should be sufficient.   Although presenting the modal view controller from within `viewDidAppear` worked for me in the iOS 5.1 simulator, [Presenting a modal view controller when loading another ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6405507/1318452) says it sometimes doesn't happen.

Comment: Wow, this was not obvious to me. I spent sometime trying to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: If this is happening upon app launch - isn't there still a flicker of the presenting view controller before the presented view controller is displayed? Any way around this? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739461/how-do-you-transition-in-a-new-non-model-view-controller-without-using-uinavigat/14739540#14739540 for context.

Comment: This is still the case for iOS 10 Xcode 8 Swift 2.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have it resolved. I was trying to present the view from view did load of the main view controller. Not sure why it does not work there, but instead I am now setting a timer which calls a method to present the view controller after the main view loads and it works fine now using...

```
[self presentViewController:requestIPViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks to those who replied.

Comment: This method is only available in iOS 6 and beyond

Comment: @NathanielSymer I don't think that's right. The docs say that presentViewController:animated:completion: is iOS5 and above. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:

Answer (score 4):

As @Dondragmer said, if you want to present your viewController in root view's viewDidLoad, it will fail.Once your viewController is ready for that, you can present your new viewController.
So, you can do that in

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    //present here
}
```

Comment: ^ depends how many times you want to present it :) Da debugger's break point showed this getting called a couple of times in quick succession.

Answer (score 0):

Present a modalViewController:

For the benefit of all starting programmers, type it instead of copy paste.

```
myVC *viewController = [[myVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"myVC" bundle:nil];
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

It looks like you were trying to present a nav controller as a view controller in the first sample, then you were using the wrong method in the second one.

Comment: Actually you are correct with regard to the presentModalViewController. I copied it wrong from my working code. I was, however, really wanting to get the presentViewController working as presentModalViewController has be deprecated. I did get it working... See my answer below.

Comment: For future reference, don't do copy/paste programming.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. But my situation is the `presentViewController` is called after the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` for another ViewController. My solution is to move the `presentViewController` to completion block of `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Comment: It makes sense. because you have to dismiss a controller before presenting another one.