# Xamarin Storyboard file

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Hi I am new to IOS development in Xamarin. I want to know if it is possible to load one storyboard from another. Because I want two separate files, each with their own navigation controller and other view controllers. Is this possible, if so how do I do it? I want to load one .stotyboard file from another. This [How to programmatically load another viewController from a ViewController in MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575124/how-to-programmatically-load-another-viewcontroller-from-a-viewcontroller-in-mon) did not work for me.

Comment: Yes you can load a different storyboard very much like the native, except the syntax. Have a look at [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10575741/1155650) or this [Xamarin Forum Question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1255/calling-a-storyboard-from-a-button-click-or-table-view-newbie)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically load another viewController from a ViewController in MonoTouch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575124/how-to-programmatically-load-another-viewcontroller-from-a-viewcontroller-in-mon)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can navigate to another Storyboard like this:

```
UIStoryboard storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("SecondStoryboard", null);
UIViewController controller = (UIViewController)storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("SecondVC");
controller.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
this.PresentViewController (controller, true, null);
```