# How do you transition in a new non-model view controller without using UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

The following seems like a typical use case: You start the app with a LoginViewController that displays the login screen. Once the user has successfully logged in, you want to show the main view for your app (let's call it MainViewController).

You don't want to put the LoginViewController into a UINavigationController and subsequently push MainViewController onto it because there's no reason to keep the LoginViewController present at the bottom of the stack since it will never be shown again. Also, in subsequent launches of the app, you'll determine that you've already got a login token of some kind and will never end up showing the LoginViewController at all so there'd be inconsistency from launch to launch of the navigation controller's stack.

You also don't want to modally present MainViewController from LoginViewController for the same reason (if it's modal it would keep the LoginViewController loaded behind).

You also don't want to set the window's rootViewController to MainViewController (where it was previously set to LoginViewController) because that won't allow you have a transition.

I'd like some feedback on whether my logic above is flawed and in fact one of these scenarios is the right one? Or if not, what are others doing for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not make the MainViewController your app's root view controller, and present the LoginViewController modally upon launch if you don't have a login token?

Comment: Hmm ok that's not a bad idea. However I'd have to ensure the MainViewController can be created without a valid login session, but I guess since it's view won't be displayed initially (it would be stacked on top of immediately) it's viewDidLoad and similar functions won't be called yet.

Comment: One follow up to this though ... if LoginViewController is on top of the navigation stack when I pop it off, the view will slide to the right to reveal MainViewController's view which iOS users have come to associate with moving back not forward. And they will probably perceive moving from Login to Main as moving forward. Thoughts?

Comment: I've done it like this before too. When you dismiss LoginViewController, you have a variety of options on how to dismiss it, it doesn't just have to be a slide to the right. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html and modalTransitionStyle

Comment: ..and @rickster doesn't mean put LoginViewController on top of the navigation stack, he means use [UIViewController presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent:animated:completion:] above the UINavigationController

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @bandejapaisa, and for the link to the transition styles, makes sense. Only thing is, I guess I can't present the LoginViewController until the MainViewController's viewDidAppear method right? That means even if I present without animation there will still be a quick flash of the main view before the login view is shown. Ways around this?

Comment: Update: looks like I can put MainViewController into window.rootViewController in applicationDidFinishLaunching and then in applicationDidBecomeActive I can check if login is needed and if so, present the LoginViewController with no animation and it seems to work without any flicker :)

Comment: Sounds lily you've pretty well figured stuff out regardless, but here's an extra two cents on the animation thing: I kinda like briefly showing the main UI and animating in the login, since that sort of emphasizes, "here's where the app normally starts, but you need to log in first".

Answer (score 2):

I have this kind of application and I have implemented by removing the LoginViewController which is the current object and and adding the TabBarController with the HomeViewController on focus like this

```
  /* remove the  current Login screen and show the 2nd tab */ 
    NSMutableArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
    [newArray removeObject:self];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newArray animated:YES];
```

when use log out from the app then I create the login screen and add to the stack, otherwise just go directly to the HomeViewController

when use log out from the app then I add the LoginViewController back on the stack and assign the current index of UITabBarController to LoginViewController something like this

```
 NSMutableArray *array =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:loginController];
        NSMutableArray* oldArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
        [array addObjectsFromArray:oldArray];

        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:array animated:YES];
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - is your LoginViewController inside of the TabBarController? Also, can you get a transition between screens with this method?

Comment: Yes logincontroller is part of tabBarController and I have done this in multiple applications without problems , by using an array can remove the loginController and after logout just add it again at first index, it is not very difficult stuff I must say

Comment: Ok but how do you specify the transition?

Comment: i make transition with my controllers with this method `-(CATransition*)addCustomAnimation{

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    
    return transition;
}
`

Comment: & when pushing the controller or showing the controller make this transition default     `[self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:[self addCustomAnimation] forKey:nil];        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newArray animated:NO];`

Comment: Fair enough, but I have to say that this approach seems a bit too "raw" for my taste and I prefer the approach in the other answer. It may be fine for your app, not trying to say it's invalid in any way, but not the way I'd prefer to do it. Thanks though.