# How to manage Log In and Log out process on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, hierarchy, loginview

I've been struggling with this a long time now, so I finally gave up on trying to find the answer and decided to ask it right away.

On my app I have a user log in page. The app has a TabBarViewController that has some NavigationControllers in it's items.

My last effort was to put the login screen embedded on a NavigationBarController and make it the Initial View Controller, as in the picture below.

[image]

When the app is launched, if the user is logged in the LogInViewController 'segues' to the TabBarController and everything is fine. When the user logs out in the ProfileViewController, there's a segue in this ViewController 'segueing' to the initial view controller.

In the other hand, if no user is logged in, the LogInViewController presents a view so that the user can insert username and password. If credentials are correct the LogInViewController 'segues' to the TabBarController. The problem is that at this point, even if the app is still working good, i get the following warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present TabBarViewController: 0xa19a670 on UINavigationController: 0xa526370 while a presentation is in progress!

So I assume this is not the best way to handle all this LogIn/LogOut process.

My question is, where should I put the LogInScreen in the hierarchy?
If by any chance my layout/hierarchy is correct, how to make the warning go away?

Comment: I've used this system a couple times and it has worked well. My `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController` (bar hidden). My initial view controller just has an image identical to my load image (users see no change). When it loads up it checks to see if a user is logged in or not, then it does a `segue` (push) with a cross fade animation to either the login screen or logged in screen. "Logout" function pops to the root of the nav controller which fades to the login page (login page looks like loading image, but with login content overlaid). Your problem sounds like implementation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your Home screen as your `rootViewController` and in once your application starts or become active, you can check if user is logged in or not, if not then present the LoginScreen Modally, it will avoid the mess with other `NavigationController` or `TabBarController`

Alternate could be to put all the `ViewControllers` in a `MutbaleArray` and set the current Index of `TabBarController` according to the view you want to show? if you don't want to show the LoginScreen after user Logged in, just remove it from your `MutableArray`, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739461/how-do-you-transition-in-a-new-non-model-view-controller-without-using-uinavigat/14739535#14739535), it might help your cause

Comment: By Home screen you mean the TabBarViewController right?
The thing is, if i present the LogInScreen in the AppDelegate, how can I get back to it when the user logs out?

Comment: yes, Whatever you are showing after user has logged in, i meant

Comment: you could use `ApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` , you don't have to go in AppDelegate then, just register your controller to this notification and do your tasks

Comment: But if the user logs out and stays in the app wanting tho log in with a different user account, the ApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is not called

Comment: yes in that way you will have to make the check, if user is logged off then it will automatically will make your case for showing login screen, you will ofcourse have a button to logout so when the user clicks the log out button it means you can have action behind this button to show the login screen again

Comment: if this case does not help you then follow my answer in the other thread where I presented the link,  MutableArray will solve your issue I am sure, I have used this technique in multiple apps which I have built.

Comment: Ended up changing the app layout and linking the LoginViewController to Home. Thanks for helping.