# Display an UIAlertView when app launches

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to add a UIAlertView or Controller when the app first loads. Currently, I have this code in my `viewDidLoad` method.

```
let welcomeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "hola", message: "this is a test.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
welcomeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok.", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

self.presentViewController(welcomeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Why won't the alert view display? I used the same code but inside of an `IBAction` for a button, and it works as expected.

Comment: That's a dup. You can't display an alert from the root VC. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147625/unable-to-get-presentviewcontroller-to-work for alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be displaying the alert in your `viewDidAppear:` function. To present a subview or another view controller, the parent view controller has to be in the view hierarchy.

> The `viewDidAppear` function "notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy."
>
> <sub>* From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:)</sub>

So, your code could look something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let welcomeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "hola", message: "this is a test.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        welcomeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok.", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(welcomeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have that in my code. I don't see a viewDidAppear. And if I insert what you have, it tells me to remove the didReceiveMemoryWarning

Comment: You have to add the function, and what is the entire error message about `didReceiveMemoryWarning`? Maybe you forgot a curly brace (`}`) when putting the code in.

Comment: Ah, I put it under the memory thing and it worked fine.